# Como disparar un FutureBuilder al hacer un SmartRefresh en flutter?

Tags: flutter, refresh

como podria disparar un future builder cuando jalo la pantalla para un refresh, estoy usando una libreria que se llama: pull_to_refresh 1.5.8

este es su enlace: [Enlace a la libreria pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh#-readme-tab-)

aqui le muestro un poco mi codigo:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
      body:  SmartRefresher(
                header: WaterDropMaterialHeader(),
                enablePullDown: true,
                onRefresh: () {


                },
                controller: refreshController ,
                child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            _fondo(),
                            _demas(context),
                        ],
                ),
    ),
      ),

  );
 }
```

y cuando haga un refresh el usuario pueda dispararse otra vez este codigo:

```
  Future<List<Punto>> obtenerElBloque( BuildContext contexto){

  CardProvider proveedorCard = new CardProvider();
  return  proveedorCard.obtenerCards(context);
 }



      Widget _myPoints(BuildContext contexto){
      List<Punto> listaPuntos = new List();
       return  new Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                          FutureBuilder(
                                future: obtenerElBloque(contexto),                                  
                                builder: ( BuildContext contexto, AsyncSnapshot 
                asyncSnapshot ) {

                                        if(asyncSnapshot.hasData){

                                              print("PASA");
                                              String mensaje;
                                              String puntos = "PUNTOS";
                                              Punto primerPunto;
                                              listaPuntos = asyncSnapshot.data;

                                              if(listaPuntos.isEmpty){
                                                    mensaje = "Ninguna informacion";
                                                    puntos = "";
                                              }else {
                                                   primerPunto = listaPuntos[0];
                                                   if(primerPunto.name == "Revise su 
                  conexion a internet"){
                                                      mensaje = primerPunto.name;
                                                      puntos = "";
                                                   } else {
                                                      if ( primerPunto.name == "Error" ) {
                                                           mensaje = primerPunto.name;
                                                           puntos = "";
                                                      } else {
                                                           mensaje = 
                   primerPunto.point[0].toString();
                                                           print(mensaje);
                                                      }  
                                                   }
                                              }
                                              return Column(
                                                     children: <Widget>[
                                                          Text( mensaje , style: TextStyle( 
             color: Colors.black , fontSize: 40.0 ), ),
                                                          Text(puntos,    style: TextStyle( 
              color: Colors.black , fontSize: 40.0 ), ),
                                                     ],
                                              ); 
                                        } else {   
                                            if( asyncSnapshot.hasError ){
                                              print(asyncSnapshot.error);
                                              return Column(
                                                     children: <Widget>[
                                                          Text( 
           asyncSnapshot.error.toString() , style: TextStyle( color: Colors.black , 
           fontSize: 40.0 ), ),
                                                     ],
                                              );
                                            }

                                            print("No hay data aun");
                                            return CircularProgressIndicator(
                                               valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color> 
    (Colors.brown),
                                            );

                                        }         
                                },
                          ),
                      ],
                 );

     }
```

la verdad he probado con setState y con una bandera bool para ver si esta cargando o no pero el setState me tira un problema. Muchas gracias , Ante algun codigo que deseen puedo proporcionarlo. gracias.

Comment: Cuando trabajas con librerías y no las comprendas, lo que tienes que hacer primero es un ejemplo muy básico, reduce tu ejemplo a algo más sencillo,  Refresh > listado  y que cada vez que hagas un pull , te traiga X datos más. Guíate del ejemplo del package. Una vez que tengas eso lo lograrás comprender, sino pues agregas el ejemplo reducido a tu pregunta para ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que unicamente con un setstate estarias obligando a que esa pantalla se refresque y el futurebuilder vuelva a cargar la funcion que usa "obtenerElBloque(contexto)". En caso de que usar el setstate de error necesitariamos el detalle del mismo y el código completo.